# How to get paragraph tag under h3 in article element?

Tags: html, css

I've got this clone script page I wrote:

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
article, aside, footer, header, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
img {
border-style: none;
}
li, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.listing-extra-detail, .listing-key-specs {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 8px 0 4px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 36px;
}
.product-card {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.product-card-content {
    width: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.product-card-content p {
margin-top: 20px;
}
.product-card-image {
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 46%;
}
.product-card-image {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.product-card-image .product-card-image__main-image {
    width: 76%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.product-card-image .product-card-image__thumbnails {
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 24%;
}
.product-card-image .product-card-image__thumbnails {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.product-card-image .product-card-image__thumbnails .product-card-image__image:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.product-card-image .product-card-image__thumbnails .product-card-image__image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 33%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.product-card-image .product-card-image__thumbnails .product-card-image__image {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.product-card-image .product-card-image__image {
    height: 100%;
    }

.product-card__inner {
    display: flex;
}
article.cont1 {
display: block;
float: right;
}
.price {
display: block;
float: right;
left: 80px;
 color: #333;
 line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<header>
CAR SALES
</header>
<article class="product-card">
<div class="product-card__inner">
<section class="product-card-image ">

        <img class="product-card-image__image product-card-image__main-image" alt="" srcset="
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w262h198pf7f7f5/6eaae6e733f747c2a0c8aab256582406.jpg 262w,
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w340h255pf7f7f5/6eaae6e733f747c2a0c8aab256582406.jpg
             " sizes="
                (max-width: 1024px) 262px,
                340px
             " src="https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w340h255pf7f7f5/6eaae6e733f747c2a0c8aab256582406.jpg" loading="lazy" data-label="search appearance click ">

            <div class="product-card-image__thumbnails">
                   <img class="product-card-image__image" loading="lazy" data-label="search appearance click " srcset="
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w84h63pf7f7f5/7c34445e3f9a43ebbec931cddb643199.jpg 84w,
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w108h81pf7f7f5/7c34445e3f9a43ebbec931cddb643199.jpg
                        " sizes="
                            (max-width: 1024px) 84px,
                            108px
                        " src="https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w108h81pdfdfdf/7c34445e3f9a43ebbec931cddb643199.jpg" alt="">
                                  <img class="product-card-image__image" loading="lazy" data-label="search appearance click " srcset="
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w84h63pf7f7f5/f4d93ea19d47498eb2227477e3834ee5.jpg 84w,
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w108h81pf7f7f5/f4d93ea19d47498eb2227477e3834ee5.jpg
                        " sizes="
                            (max-width: 1024px) 84px,
                            108px
                        " src="https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w108h81pdfdfdf/f4d93ea19d47498eb2227477e3834ee5.jpg" alt="">
                                  <img class="product-card-image__image" loading="lazy" data-label="search appearance click " srcset="
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w84h63pf7f7f5/9bd4e22610ba46429ace7689b13fd2e6.jpg 84w,
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w108h81pf7f7f5/9bd4e22610ba46429ace7689b13fd2e6.jpg
                        " sizes="
                            (max-width: 1024px) 84px,
                            108px
                        " src="https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w108h81pdfdfdf/9bd4e22610ba46429ace7689b13fd2e6.jpg" alt="">
               
            </div>
    </section>
    <div class="product-card-content">
    <h3>Vauxhall Mokka 1.6</h3>
    <p>2015, 65, silver, 8,000 miles</p>
    </div>
<!-- 
    <article class="cont1">
    <h3>Vauxhall Mokka 1.6</h3>
    <p>2015</p>
    </article>
 -->
<div class="price">
<h3>£21,990</h3>
</div>
</div>
</article>

<article class="product-card">
<div class="product-card__inner">
<section class="product-card-image ">

        <img class="product-card-image__image product-card-image__main-image" alt="" srcset="
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w262h198pf7f7f5/6eaae6e733f747c2a0c8aab256582406.jpg 262w,
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w340h255pf7f7f5/6eaae6e733f747c2a0c8aab256582406.jpg
             " sizes="
                (max-width: 1024px) 262px,
                340px
             " src="https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w340h255pf7f7f5/6eaae6e733f747c2a0c8aab256582406.jpg" loading="lazy" data-label="search appearance click ">
    </section>
    <div class="product-card-content">
    <h3>Vauxhall Mokka 1.6</h3>
    <p>2015, 65, silver, 8,000 miles</p>
    </div>
<!-- 
    <article class="cont1">
    <h3>Vauxhall Mokka 1.6</h3>
    <p>2015</p>
    </article>
 -->
<div class="price">
<h3>£21,990</h3>
</div>
</div>
</article>
```

View the snippet as full page to see the problem.

This is the part that's causing the biggest problem:

```
 <div class="product-card-content">
<h3>Vauxhall Mokka 1.6</h3>
<p>2015, 65, silver, 8,000 miles</p>
</div>
```

It works, but the

element does not go under the h3 as I'd expected; I've tried margin-top and margin-bottom etc.

The text is always at the bottom of  and I can't figure out why.

This template works well enough, but I cannot figure out how to fix this problem ; it's a slowly ongoing process creating this template.

Comment: You have `justify-content:space-between` in your `product-card-content` `class` and the `div` is occupying the whole `height` of the `parent`. You may want to change it to `justify-content: flex-start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to to use `justify-content: start` to have content at the top of the element `div`:

```
.product-card-content {
    width: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All elements have default margins assigned to them by browser. Just reset them first by putting `h3, p {margin:0}` and then on your parent div change `.product-card-content {justify-content: start}`
That worked for me.

If this is what you are asking for.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdWtS.png)